# How do I force save the dbpath parameter?

Tags: mongodb, config

I'm just starting out with developing with Mongodb locally and following the tutorials.

I want to use 1 path for all my development.

In the Mongodb documentation it says:

> Create a data directory
>
> By default MongoDB will store data in
>   /data/db, but it won't automatically
>   create that directory. To create it,
>   do:
>
> $ mkdir -p /data/db
>
> You can also tell
>   MongoDB to use a different data
>   directory, with the --dbpath option.

I want to use one path for all my dbpaths so that I know where they all are and not get confused.

The path I want to use is:

```
sudo mongod --config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mongodb/mongodb.conf
```

The mongodb.conf file I have is set up as thus:

```
# Store data alongside MongoDB instead of the default, /data/db/
dbpath = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mongodb

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

However, I have noticed that I have to keep typing this config path in every time I want to run Mongo.

How do I make it so that Mongodb save the dbpath, or the path to the config without me having to type it out every time?

Thanks.

Comment: I should point out that I am on a Mac Snow Lepoard, and the reason why I want it pointing to my XAMPP directory is so I can use Mango with XAMPP. For some reason, any basic Mongo test php script I do will not be recognized unless I store the mongodb inside the dbpath under the XAMPP folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a bash script that runs the commands you want.

Make a file called startMongo.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
mongod --config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mongodb/mongodb.conf
```

Run command

```
sudo startMongo.sh
```

Comment: and of course make sure its executable.  chmod +x startMongo.sh

Comment: I've not written bash scripts before, but I'll see if I can do this and go from there.

Comment: Where do I save the startMongo.sh file?  Do I need to save it in the bin/bash folder, or can it be anywhere?

Comment: I created the file and put it in the same directory as the .conf file, but sudo startMongo.sh doesn't work.  I had to use `$ sudo /bin/bash startMongo.sh`.  I entered chmod +x startMongo.sh, but this still requires me to enter the sudo /bin/bash part at my terminal line.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For future readers: `$ sudo ./startMongo.sh` where the startMongo.sh is.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a startup script, like a bash/cshc script. You must specify those options when starting up.